# Getting error using OData v4 Web API Scaffolding

Tags: visual-studio-2017, odata, scaffolding

I am currently getting the following error
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r97RB.png)
When i try to scaffold a controller using OData v4 Web API Scaffolding.

I have a couple of work colleagues which it does work using visual studio 2017 even though it doesnt seem to be supported by vs 2017 . Any advice on the matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Officially Visual Studio 2017 is not in supported list of "OData v4 Web API Scaffolding" And Q&A section states that this package has a open bug for Visual Studio 2017.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LiangWangMSFT.ODatav4WebAPIScaffolding#qna

But you can go for one of following work around:

1. Use this template in Visual Studio 2015 and then continue
   development.
2. Add "Microsoft.AspNet.OData" Package and add Controller
   manually. You can use code generated from V3 (just few namespace
   correction will be required).